# find all the different biggest subnets that are supernet among subnets in a list of subnets in Python

Tags: python, network-programming, python-ipaddress

i am having a list of subnets and i need to find all the biggest subnets from a list of subnets that are supernets among subnets present in the list.

example

`subnetList = ['10.10.0.0/16', '10.10.10.10/32', '192.168.56.0/24', '10.0.0.0/8']`

so output here `['10.0.0.0/8', '192.168.56.0/24']`   are the two top level supernet among different subnet present in the list

to solve this i am currently using using implementation using ipaddress python lib,

is there any better implementation !!!!
since this problem seems to be like finding multiple max of different types present in a list

```
import ipaddress

inputS = ['172.16.0.0/16' ,'10.10.0.0/16', '10.10.10.10/32', '172.16.1.0/24', '10.10.10.0/24', '172.16.10.10/32', '192.168.56.0/24', '10.0.0.0/8']
inputS = list(set(inputS))
input = []

for each in inputS:
    input.append(ipaddress.ip_network(str(each)))

input1 = input

for i in range(len(input)):
    for j in range(len(input1)):
        if str(input[i]) != str(input1[j]):
            if input[i].supernet_of(input1[j]):
                input1[j] = input[i]

output = []

for each in input1:
    output.append(str(each))

print(list(set(output)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ipaddress library in python has a function [collapse_addresses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html). collapse_addresses function should be able to give you a direct output of supernets from the list of input ipaddresses.

Please check the below code snippet:

```
>>> import ipaddress
>>> inputS = ['172.16.0.0/16' ,'10.10.0.0/16', '10.10.10.10/32', '172.16.1.0/24', '10.10.10.0/24', '172.16.10.10/32', '192.168.56.0/24', '10.0.0.0/8']
>>> input_ips = [ipaddress.ip_network(x) for x in inputS]
>>> res = ipaddress.collapse_addresses(input_ips)
>>> print([x for x in res])
[IPv4Network('10.0.0.0/8'), IPv4Network('172.16.0.0/16'), IPv4Network('192.168.56.0/24')]
```